# Those of meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "those of" mean in this sentence? What is the difference beetwen two sentences?

> 1. She met those of a large carpetillar
> 2. She met a large carpetillar.

> She stretched herself up on tiptoe, and peeped over the edge of the mushroom, and her eyes immediately met **those of** a large caterpillar, that was sitting on the top with its arms folded, quietly smoking a long hookah, and taking not the smallest notice of her or of anything else.

Source:https://www.storynory.com/alice-in-wonderland-chapter-4/

Comment: I've edited.  Don't use  <br> to make paragraphs.  Just use a blank line.  The formatting language isn't HTML, it is markdown, and it looks better if you avoid HTML tags as much as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "those" is a pronoun, and refers to something. It's plural so it must refer to a plural somethings.

Looking at the quote you should realise that it says

> Her eyes met *those* of a large caterpillar.

"Those" refers to "eyes" so this could be paraphrased as

> Her eyes met *the eyes of* a large caterpillar.

With the idiomatic use of "their eyes met", meaning "they looked at each other.

And "She met those of a large caterpillar" is incorrect English.

Comment: Thank you. Something similar has been on my mind and i want to ask you.<<<<`Did you say pig, or fig?' said the Cat.

`I said pig,' replied Alice; `and I wish you wouldn't keep appearing and vanishing so suddenly: you make on quite giddy.'

`All right,' said the Cat; and this time it vanished quite slowly, beginning with the end of the tail, and ending with the grin, which remained some time after the rest of it had gone. >>>>. What does "the rest of" mean in this sentence? Source:https://www.storynory.com/alice-in-wonderland-chapter-6/

Comment: @James K I don't think you mean "**a** plural something**s**". I'd fix it, but I don't know which one you'd remove.